# Core Data: sum/avg of attribute values only if > 0 or !=@""

Tags: objective-c, core-data, key-value-coding

I have an entity attribute in which are stored both numbers and empty field.
I need the sum and the average values of this attributes values but doing `@"@sum.attributeName"` or `@"@avg.attributeName"` I get

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSDecimalNumberOverflowException', reason: 'NSDecimalNumber overflow exception'

Thank's

Comment: What data type is your attributeName? It sounds like it's string data type.

Comment: Your code is trying to get sum/average of string. It doesn't work because it works just on numeric values.

Comment: I can confirm that even if it is NSString it works until there are only numbers... The problem starts when there are empty values. Is there a way to not include the empty values in the @avg or @sum?

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574782/core-data-how-to-display-results-of-a-fetchrequest-for-calculating-values-in-a/17607207#17607207)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved even if the Attributes are String Type as follows:

```
 NSArray *allValues = [array valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfObjects.entityAttribute"];
NSMutableArray *allNumberValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


for (int i=0; i<valoriVotoEsame.count; i++) {

    if (            ![[allValues objectAtIndex:i] isEqual:@""])
    {
        [allNumberValues addObject:[allValues objectAtIndex:i]];


    }

}
```